# Magento 2 set due amount zero when invoice generate programmatically

Tags: magento2

I am generating invoice of due amount of order. But due amount is not set zero after generating invoice.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Paymentmethod\Model;

use Namespace\Paymentmethod\Api\BraintreePaylaterPaymentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Namespace\Core\Helper\CommonRequest;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction;
use Namespace\CoreAdminOrder\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;
use Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapterFactory;
use Magento\Braintree\Gateway\Config\Config;

class BraintreePaylaterPayment implements BraintreePaylaterPaymentInterface
{
    protected $orderRepository;

    protected $commonRequestHelper;

    protected $invoiceService;

    protected $transaction;

    protected $coreHelper;

    protected $invoiceSender;

    protected $braintreeAdapterFactory;

    protected $braintreeConfig;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param CommonRequest $commonRequestHelper
     * @param InvoiceService $invoiceService
     * @param Transaction $transaction
     * @param Data $coreHelper
     * @param InvoiceSender $invoiceSender
     * @param BraintreeAdapterFactory $braintreeAdapterFactory
     * @param Config $braintreeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        CommonRequest $commonRequestHelper,
        InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        Transaction $transaction,
        Data $coreHelper,
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        BraintreeAdapterFactory $braintreeAdapterFactory,
        Config $braintreeConfig
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_commonRequestHelper = $commonRequestHelper;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->transaction = $transaction;
        $this->coreHelper = $coreHelper;
        $this->invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        $this->braintreeAdapterFactory = $braintreeAdapterFactory;
        $this->braintreeConfig = $braintreeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Returns boolen 
     *
     * @api
     * @param  int $orderId Order ID.
     * @param  string $paymentMethod Payment Method.
     * @param  string $paymentMethodNonce Nonce code that given by Braintree.
     * @return array
     */

    public function generateInvoiceForOrder($orderId, $amount, $transactionId, $paymentMethod, $storeId)
    {
        try {
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

            foreach ($orderItems as $value) {
                $itemsArray[$value->getId()] = $value->getQtyOrdered();
            }

            $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $itemsArray);

            if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('You can\'t create an invoice without products.')
                );
            }

            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
            $invoice->register();

            $transactionSave = $this->transaction->addObject(
                $invoice
            )->addObject(
                $invoice->getOrder()
            );

            $transactionSave->save();
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);

            $amount = $this->coreHelper->getPriceFormatByStore($storeId, $amount);
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Payment Made Using '.$paymentMethod.', Captured amount of '.$amount.' online. Transaction ID: '.$transactionId)
            )
            ->setStatus('payment_received')
            ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
            ->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new InputException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return $invoice->getEntityId();
    }
}
```

Anyone have idea,Please suggest me ?

Comment: Update your code to the question what you have tried.

Comment: updated question.